# EMV - How to create Terminal Transaction Qualifiers

Tags: emv

I want to develop Entry Point to read contactless card. I was read some specification documents about Terminal Transaction Qualifier (TTQ). But i don't know how to create value of it? What is bit turn on/off?

[TTQ follow by EMV document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxu7i.png)

And my question is how to determine value of TTQ?

Sorry my English is not good.

Answer (score 0):

POS Subsystem is split into reader, kernel and entry point. Download from EMVCo website the complete specification and understant what is expected from entrypoint and kernel perspectices. There are 9 in total

- architecture(1)
- Entry Point specification(1)
- Kernel specification for each( 7, one for each payment scheme ).

Go through 1, 2 and the relavant kernel spec from third.

Comment: Thanks you for support. I was read book A, book B and book C-3, but i don't understand about Zero amount allowed flag and Zero amount for offline allowed flag. Please, can you share for me some documents about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find values of TTQ here.
https://emv.cool/2020/12/24/Terminal-Transaction-Qualifiers-TTQ-9F66-qPBOC/

It's only VISA tag as far as I know.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.